# Get the info if a changeset was merged from one branch to another

Tags: tfs

in TFS2010, would it be possible to obtain** information if a changeset was merged from one branch to another?
The "query" would take source and target branches as parameters and then return yes / no information for each changeset if it was merged.

** Obtain - via ordinary query? Or maybe in more sophisticated way. I'm a collection administrator, do not have access to TFS database, but if I had, would it be hard to code that query?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [track changeset](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vn7hsiuO8b4)?

Comment: It's management issue, track changset is excellent feature to check merging history for a single task. If it comes to check merging history for let's say hundred of tasks, there's the problem. But thx for a tip.

Comment: You're right - it sounds like there is a "Management Issue" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TF Merges Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/656cs2x5) should help, use the changeset as the versionspec

Comment: That should suffice but for unknown reason I'm constantly getting  "Registration.asmx could not be contacted.HTTP status: 404" response. While specifying the collection I pass URL displayed in the properties of server I'm connected to followed by /Project Name, it looks like that: tf merges trunk rel /collection:"http://myServer.com:8090/tfs/collectionName/Project Name". Notice there's a space in Project Name. Any suggestions where's the problem?

Comment: Can you connect ok using visual studio? Does it have exactly the same URL?

Comment: Ok, I've figured out the problem, case is to pass both (source and target) branches as <project>/<branch>. Correct command is as follows: tf merges "$/Project Name/trunk" "$/Project Name/branches/rel" /collection:"myServer.com:8090/tfs/collectionName".

Comment: And where does the versionspec go?  I always hated the tfs help. :(